# Runtime exec cannot run programs in appdata?

Tags: java

I have been messing around with running some .exe files and it appears as if there is something blocking it from running it in appdata?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "test.exe");
```

This is the error I get

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Cole": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You're not escaping spaces.

Comment: There are BTW 3 related questions which expand a bit more on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the plain exec(String) method as it requires OS specific escaping. If you use the [string array version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) it should find the executable.

It is also a good idea to check if the variable exists and if it ends with a `\` before concatenating it with the filename. Or better use the hierachical File constructor:

```
String appdata = System.getenv("APPDATA");
if (appdata == null || appdata.trim().isEmpty())
  appdata=".";
String fileName = new File(appdata, "test.exe").getAbsolutePath();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{fileName /*, noargs */});
```

Comment: could you give an example on how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to construct the path using a File object.

```
final String f = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA"), "test.exe").toString();
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { f });
```